# Functional Analysis study reference requests.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, self-learning

I’m currently studying for an exam in Functional analysis.

I have already gone through my homework assignments and lecture notes and would like to practice some more problems. My professor isn’t using a specific textbook so I am not sure what would be the best place to pull practice problems from.

Some of the main topics we’ve covered since our last exam include: adjoint operators, self-adjoint operators, compact sets and compact operators, Spectral theorem, and Singular value decomposition, all of which is in the setting of Hilbert Spaces.

What would be some suggestions for textbooks to pull problems from to help prepare for my exam.

Comment: I have heard good things about *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications* by Kreyzsig, although I don't know if it would be the best source of exercises. The text I used for my operator theory course was *Theory of Linear operators in Hilbert space* by Akhiezer and Glazman.

Comment: Here you can find the homework problems (with solutions) from my course: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/14SPRINGTEA/math7334.html I hope they are useful.

Comment: *Functional Analysis* by Bachman and Narici covers very similar material, and has lots of reasonable exercises.